# How can I transform a Go validator.FieldLevel.Field() to string array

Tags: arrays, validation, go, go-playground

I have a complex object with this structure.

```golang
type People struct {
    Objectives    []string  `validate:"required,ValidateCustom" json:"Objectives"`
}
```

And I need to test the list thinking in a enum, using `gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9`:

```golang
//ValidateCustom -- ValidateCustom
func ValidateCustom(field validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    switch strings.ToUpper(field.Field().String()) {
    case "emumA":
    case "enumB":
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

This example uses a idea of string but how can I build to []string to iterate?

Comment: What is `validator`?

Comment: its a gopkg validator for entities... gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9

Answer (score 1):

I founded the answer... using slice and Interface

```
//ValidateCustom -- ValidateCustom
func ValidateCustom(field validator.FieldLevel) bool {
  inter := field.Field()
  slice, ok := inter.Interface().([]string)
  if !ok {
      return false
  }
  for _, v := range slice {
      switch strings.ToUpper(v) {
         case "enumA":
         case "enumB":
           return true
         default:
           return false
     }
}
```